# Group notification wont show

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM to send notifications between users when they receive a new message.

I had like to make a group notification from my app so it will show like this:

[image]

However, for some reason every new notification that I get, it deletes the other so it always shows only the latest notification.

My code is:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private FirebaseFirestore db;

    private static String GROUP_KEY = "NOTIFICATION";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        createNotificationChannel();
        notifyThis(remoteMessage.getData().get("title"),remoteMessage.getData().get("body"),remoteMessage.getData().get("var1"),remoteMessage.getData().get("var2"),remoteMessage.getData().get("var3"));
        
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            CharSequence name = "ABC";
            String description = "ABCDE";
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("191919", name, importance);
            channel.setDescription(description);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }
    }

    public void notifyThis(String title, String message, String var1, String var2, String var3) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ChatActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra("ChatID",var1);
        intent.putExtra("ReceiverID",var2);
        intent.putExtra("itemID",var3);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "191919")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_custom_background)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(message)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_DEFAULT)
                .setGroup(GROUP_KEY)
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        notificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());

    }

}
```

Is there any reason? Any chance that it is because of the `channelId`?

Also, I saw that I might need to build multiple notifications however how can I make it dynamic based on the amount of messages that the user gets?

Lets set I get 2 notifications and then I get one more message but I built only 2 notifications, how it will show me the third?

Thank you

Comment: You need to build the group summary, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52929431/10470378)

Comment: I looked at this, however, how can I make it dynamic? Let say now I have 1 unread message but in 2 minutes someone else sending a message and now I should have already 2 notification in that box.